# search double case in mongodb in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

here my code in model is

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
     where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

Now i want to add another field also to search 
like

```
where(price: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i)
```

So my query should search two field 
like

```
 where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i) (or)  where(price: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i)
```

How to add this two field in mongodb like or . Working example is accepted.
Since i have less knowledge about mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Mongoid 3, you can write your query like this:

```
self.or({name: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i}, {price: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i})
```

If you are using something other than Mongoid 3 (like MongoMapper or Mongoid 2), please give the name and version number.

**Source:** Selection syntax docs for Mongoid 3 are [here](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#standard).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    `where('$or' => [{"name" => "/#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i"}, {"price" => "/#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i"}])`

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?